# React.js onChange <input> tag hangs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As I want to get the name through input tag. Whenever I tried to enter some value, only one letter is type and then the input box comes into its ideal position. It is got hang or stuck, I really won't understand. I clear that this code is working in my another project so it is really weird.

```
const [name, setName] = useState('')

<input type='text' placeholder='Name' class='inputColor width90' name='n' 
    onChange={(e)=>{
        setName(e.target.value)
    }}
required/>
```

Here is my css for above code

```
.inputColor{
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 0px solid;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 18px;
    outline: none;
    height: 35px;
}
.width90{
    width: 90%;
}
```

But when I run the code without using **onChange** function, the input box is not stuck or hang. I check the syntax as many time but I don't know why it is happening.

Hope someone gives me the best solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `value={name}`

```
<input 
    type='text' 
    placeholder='Name' 
    class='inputColor width90' 
    name='n' 
    value={name} 
    onChange={(e)=> {
        setName(e.target.value)
    }}
    required
/>
```

The reason is because if you have an `onChange` it means that you are trying to set the value dynamically, that's why you need to set the `value` to the value of `name`

Comment: So, we have to explicitly define name as a variable because it shows ```Unexpected use of 'name'  no-restricted-globals

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.```

Comment: Name is already defined here `const [name, setName] = useState('')` on which line is the error referring to?

Comment: So, how the name is assign to value, since first we define it as empty string...

Comment: Is your component a `class` based component or a `function` based component? can you please show more code of your component?

Comment: My code is function based... Now each time I had to click on input box to enter a character...
```

```

Comment: Not sure why it is not working, if you can post more of your component I can look if I can see why.

Comment: Now each time I had to click on input box to enter a character and whenever I clicked on another input box... The first one got disappear.

Comment: Wait, I am posting the whole piece of code.

Comment: I edited the post...with all of the component related to input box.

Comment: From the code you posted all looks good, assuming you are setting up a `useState` for `appName` and `stAppName`

Comment: yes! I use something like `const [appName, setAppName] = useState('')`

Comment: Is there any other way to implement this... because I tried all my best but I haven't achieve the text from input tag.

Comment: Now my error is completely resolve.... As I define all the varibale incuding my submit button function inside the function contains all form elements. Somehow as follows:

Comment: That is why I asked you to post your code for the whole component, in that case I would have seen the issue and point it out to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here I found the actual cause or whatever we say to it, we cannot identify it because it doesnot show any error on console and successfully compile the program.

```
const MyFunc = () => {

    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    
    const submitData = () => {
            Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/upload',{
                 n: name
            }
     }

     return (
          <div class='myCSS'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src={myimg} alt={myimg}/>
                    </td><td>
                        <input type='text' name='n' placeholder='Name' 
                            class='inputColor width90' 
                            onChange={(e)=>{setName(e.target.value)}}
                        required/>
                    </td><td>
                        <input type='submit' value='upload'
                             onClick={submitData}/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
     )
}
```

So, firstly I define the `name` variable and the `submitData` outside `MyFunc` but when I define both of them inside the function, the hang or stuck error resolved.